# Как безопасно развернуть сайт под управлением git на хостинге.

Tags: linux, git, сервер

Я уже весь интернет перерыла и нигде не могу найти внятных решений.

Везде вижу только:
"Публичный доступ к служебным каталогам DCVS все еще достаточно актуальное явление. Зачастую это крайне опасно для вашего сайта - необходимо в срочном порядке закрыть доступ к таким каталогам (.git, .hg, .bzr и т.д.) и к файлам игнорирования (.gitignore, .hgignore и т.д.)."
И невнятные рецепты для продвинутых пользователей, коим я пока не являюсь!

Подскажите кто-нибудь, что конкретно нужно сделать?

Есть сайт на виртуальном хостинге? Для переноса на него правок я использую git  репозиторий, связаный с общийм репозиторием на том же сервере, в который пушу правки со своего локального компьютера.

Мне этот способ показался удобней, чем заливать исправленные файлы на сервер вручную.
Я только начинаю вникать во все тонкости веб разработки, поэтому если кому то покажется этот метод совсем глупым, то подскажите как правильно.

Comment: просто в правилах вебсервера (.htaccess или vhost для апача ) запретите доступ к .git либо в хуке git на апдейт делайте rsync. с пропуском директорий типа .git 
я вот [тут подобное решение описывал](/questions/253713#253720) к нему могу добавить что там надо бы очередь заданий на publish, делать, но у нас было на тот момент мало народу, поэтому конфликт паблиша не случался

Comment: если используете github.com, то там можно сделать [webhook](https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044) - на свой сайт добавляете небольшой скрипт и после пуша в github сайт будет автоматом обновляться.

Comment: Спасибо большое за отклик! Первый вариант для меня более понятный, сама уже додумалась почитать про .htaccess)) А где он должен быть расположен в самой директории .git или в прямо в корне сайта?

Comment: в корне, прям в реп его добавьте.

Comment: Спасибо! Прямо забрезжил свет в окошке, втрой день бьюсь над этой темой))

Comment: закрывать? вообще обычно `git clone project` переносится проект в нужное место без служебных директорий/файлов типа .git, .gitignore

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню, Апач все директории начинающиеся с точки сам закрывает (хотя может с `.ht`). Но я всегда еще сам прописываю, если директория `.git` лежит в веб директории. Комментарии на английском думаю не нуждаются в переводе:

```
# Block access to "hidden" directories or files whose names begin with a
# period. This includes directories used by version control systems such as
# Subversion or Git.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\.git" - [F]
</IfModule>

# Block access to backup and source files. These files may be left by some
# text/html editors and pose a great security danger, when anyone can access
# them.
<FilesMatch "(\.(bak|config|sql|fla|psd|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
  Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

А вообще лучше в проекте делать директорию `htdocs`, `www` или `web` например и уже туда настроить `DocumentRoot` для сервера. Тогда можно будет не волноваться за скрытые файлы.